# "Sharing disabled, view only", Share is greyed out

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive-shared-folder

Having just upgraded to Business Standard to get Shared Drives, I am trying to figure out how the sharing and inheritance works. It's quite different from My Drive.  I created a few folders, shared some of them with an external user who is NOT a "member" of the whole shared drive.  Then I removed a Member (someone else), and all the folders that had NOT been shared separately now have a greyed-out Share icon (if selected), and the tooltip says "Sharing disabled - '*Folder name*' is view-only".  Immediately putting that Member back on the shared drive did not reverse this.  What happened, and why?  Is it permanent?  If not, how can I reverse it?

Comment: I'm doing this all as the Manager, of course. I'm the only Manager on the member list. Some Members are within the organization, some external. Adding and removing an organization person does the same thing as adding and removing an external one.  A new folder created alongside the greyed-out-share ones gets a Share that is not disabled.

Comment: Using the v3 API and Files:get with [fields=*] shows no material difference between a folder where Share is greyed out, and another in the same parent where it is available.  The only attributes that differ are createdTime, id, modifiedByMeTime, modifiedTime, name (of course), version (??), viewedByMeTime, and webViewLink.  The sharable file has version=4, after I had trashed and re-made it a few times trying to figure this out; the non-sharable file has version=1.  All "capabilities" are identical.  'canShare': True on both. If I make another new folder, it has a Share icon active, for now.

Comment: Switching to Grid View and back to List View restores the Share icon and function, sometimes.